# Popup gallery for user, wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, media

I added a button to my website that pop up a gallery, my problem is that the gallery is loading the image from the code, so when my client needs to upload a new image I need to add it for him in the code also. how can I make it update auto? I mean when the client will add an image to “media” in WordPress, so the gallery will update auto, thanks!

here is the code im using right now:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-133 aligncenter" style="border: 5px solid white; border-radius: 50%; background: white; box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" alt="" width="72" height="72" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"><strong>try</strong>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" alt="Nature and sunrise" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this shotcode it's going to work i think

```
<?php
function your_custom_gallery() {
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_status'    => null,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ) );
    ?>

    <div id="imyModal" class="modal" style="direction: ltr!important;">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'original' );
                echo '<div class="mySlides">';
                echo '<div class="numbertext"> ' . $i . ' / 4</div>';
                echo '<img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" style="width:100%">';
                echo '</div>';
                $i ++;
            }
            ?>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function add_script_to_head() {
    ?>
    <script>
        function openModal() {
            document.getElementById('imyModal').style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            document.getElementById('imyModal').style.display = "none";
        }

        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            if (n > slides.length) {
                slideIndex = 1
            }
            if (n < 1) {
                slideIndex = slides.length
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
            captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_script_to_head' );
add_shortcode( 'custom_gallery', 'your_custom_gallery' );
```